# R: Create ID based on two different variables

Tags: r, grouping

I am a beginner trying to work with R, but constantly hitting walls.

I have a giant dataset (thousands of entries) that looks like this: there is a column for Latitude, Longitude and PlotCode.

[image: Table]

I have more than one plot per Longitude and Latitude. I would like to create a new column with some sort of ID to all plots with the same latitude and Longitude.

Something that will look like this in the end:

[image: Table 2]

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! It's better to add data, desired outputs, attempts and so on in your question. However maybe you can find a solution with the package `dplyr`.

After installing it, you could do this:

```
library(dplyr)
  # some data like yours
    data_latlon <- data.frame(Lat = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
                              , Long = c(45,45,45,12,12,12,23,23,23)
                              , PlotCode = c('a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'))

data_latlon %>%                                            # the pipe operator to have dplyr chains                                      
group_by(Lat,Long) %>%                                     # group by unique Lat and Long
summarise(PlotCodeGrouped = paste(PlotCode,collapse=''))   # add a new column that collapse all the plot,
                                                           # you can specify how to separate 
                                                           # with the collapse option, in 
                                                           # this case nothing
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Lat [?]
    Lat  Long PlotCodeGrouped
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          
1     1    45 aaa            
2     2    12 bbb            
3     3    23 ccc
```

*EDIT*

It's easier the code as you'd like the result:

```
data_latlon %>%                         # the pipe operator to have dplyr chains                                      
  group_by(Lat,Long, add=TRUE)          # group by unique Lat and Long
                                        # and add a ""hierarchical father"

# Groups:   Lat, Long [3]
    Lat  Long PlotCode
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>   
1    1.   45. a       
2    1.   45. a       
3    1.   45. a       
4    2.   12. b       
5    2.   12. b       
6    2.   12. b       
7    3.   23. c       
8    3.   23. c       
9    3.   23. c
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I didn't know how to describe what I needed. I edited the question to make it clearer :)

Comment: Added the edited answer, you can get a simplest code with `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution, what I needed is something called cluster ID.

```
dataframe <- transform(dataframe, Cluster_ID = as.numeric(interaction(Lat, Long, drop=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

By grouping you mean sort / arrange them by PlotCode?

if so you can use sort function or you can use arrange function through
tidyverse / dplyr package

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I didn't know how to explain what I need. I need some sort of the same ID to all plots inside the same Lat/Lon.